# Inline if statement for puppet parameters

Tags: puppet

I have a following puppet module

```
class base (
  $someBoolean=false,
)
{
  exec { 'Do something':
    command     => '/usr/bin/someStuff',
    timeout     => (someBoolean) ? 100000000 : 300
  }
}
```

The `timeout => () ? :` is enssentially what I want to do, but what is the correct syntax to do it? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Puppet's version of the ternary operator is the more general "[selector](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/reference/lang_conditional.html#selectors)".  The syntax for your case looks like this:

```
exec { 'Do something':
  command => '/usr/bin/someStuff',
  timeout => $someBoolean ? { true => 100000000, default => 300 }
}
```

The control expression (`$someBoolean` in the above) can in fact be any expression that produces a value, and any number of corresponding cases can be provided.

Comment: How to check some condition inline instead of variable. eg:               exec { 'Do something':
  command => '/usr/bin/someStuff',
  timeout => (1<2) ? { true => 100000000, default => 300 }
}

Comment: @user2885077, the control expression of a selector does not need to be a variable reference.  It can be any expression that evaluates to a value, and the value it takes governs which option is selected as the overall selector's resulting value.  Indeed, the example you present appears well-formed.  It ought to work, at least on Puppet 4+ (as I write this, the latest is v5.4), but I am uncertain whether it will work as desired on earlier, obsolete versions, as there have been changes related to data typing.